# Cannot start windows phone 10 emulator

Tags: windows, windows-10-mobile

I am not able to start any of the Mobile Emulators for Windows Phone 10 (version 10.0.10240).

When I start it from the VS 2015, it gets stuck at "OS is starting". In the Hyper-V Manager, I can see the status "Starting (10%)" for the whole time. After some time, the machine is automatically restarted and it gets stuck at "Starting (10%)" again. Then it timeouts again and the emulator shows an error: "The virtual machine cannot be started because the file rdvgm.exe that is required to start the RemoteFX Manager process does not exist". That is weird, because I do have the rdvgm.exe in the C:\Windows\System32.

I have seen that there are some questions with the same error, but they are resolved by fixing the network switch or by killing devenv.exe after it shows "OS is starting". I have tried both, but it did not help. The network switch issue is different (I have seen it on a different computer - in that case the emulator starts correctly, but VS is not able to connect to it). I am stuck at "Starting (10%)".

What can I try to get it working? Windows Phone 8 emulator is working without any issue.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck on solving this error? I have the same problem. The Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch also has a status of No Connection.

Comment: If you have exactly the same issue as me, modify the created VM, remove its GPU. Then, if you try to start it, it should start. The problem really is with the RemoteFx, it is not able to initialize it. When you remove the GPU, it starts without any problem. However, there are issues. For example, if you try to rotate the device, it will not change the resolution (so the device is horizontal, but the the OS is still in portrait mode). I will try the solution proposed by P4tr3ck, it may be the issue and if so, I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that Hyper-V detected a graphic card which is able to work with RemoteFX (integrated Intel GPU) but the dedicated one (AMD Radeon) was not supported. I was not able to convince Hyper-V to ignore the dedicated one. When I disabled the RemoteFX support for Hyper-V (unchecked it in the Intel GPU setting in the Hyper-V configuration), it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Microsoft technical support desk yesterday. Its an on line chat with their technical people. I don't know if it covers all MS products. I was asking them about Outlook. Could be worth a try. I found it a touch slow at times, but ...

https://www.awasa.microsoft.com/en-GB/consultation/index?id=914801398064643&skuId=0

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V has problems enabling RemoteFX with some dual gpu graphics cards. Disabling one of the graphics cards in device manager solved the problem for me:

- Disable one of the integrated graphics cards in device manager. I disabled Intel (R) HD Graphics 4600 and left NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M enabled.
- Reboot Windows.
- Delete the existing mobile phone virtual machines in Hyper-V Manager.
- Start Visual Studio and deploy your app again.

Comment: The problem is few machines like my ROG G750 do not have integrated GPU enabled. But Hyper-V might be getting confused with present on HD4x graphics and NVidia GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, with much distress, I performed a complete factory reset. Reinstalled only Visual Studio 2015 Community edition (only with the tools I needed and not any other emulators such as Android), and it worked after setting up Hyper V as instructed via documentation on dev.windows.com

Comment: Would you mind providing a link to said Hyper-V documentation? searching Hyper-V on dev.windows.com turns up only WIndows-8 related stuff.